# Record not insert in table, INNODB table is full in MySql Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, innodb

I Created a table  with engine InnoDB enginge

**OS is Ubuntu.**

Table Structure :

```
#ID int(11),
userID int(11),
Tokens varchar(100),
created_date Datetime
```

Current table detail
Data Rows
**42180773**
Data Free
**661651456**

Data Length
**2578464768**

Index Length
**3842785280**

Auto Increments
**72437133**

I remove some old rows then able to insert new records.
What is the issue with this table?

Comment: No, HD Space is available approx 80 GB

Comment: Which OS runs the server?

Comment: There are some OS limitations. Look here if one of them hits you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: Please provide the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there may be something subtle that you did not mention.

Comment: Please provide an actual statement that causes the error, together with the actual error message.